# Generate 2 item combinations of every 3 items in a list

Tags: python, list, combinations

I want group a list by items of 3, and iterate over each such group by 2-item combinations as concisely as possible. I tried a couple things one of which that is not even compiling:

```
from itertools import combinations
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for a,b in combinations(zip(*[iter(L)]*3), 2): 
    print "{0:d} {1:d}".format(a,b)
```

**Expected Output**

```
1,2
1,3
2,3
4,5
4,6
5,6
```

I can do this by with imperative statements but I am looking for a declarative way.

Comment: Why a declarative way? imho that's unpythonic (in this case)

Comment: Since you're already importing itertools, you might want to consider using `izip` instead of `zip` for your grouper as well.

Comment: @jamylak, I'm not clear on what is pythonic, which is probably subjective. But it seems like Python tries to be as declarative as possible.

Comment: @perreal nope that is completely wrong... The imperative way is the *"one way to do it"*, it's practical, simple and readable (in this case), the *declarative* solutions are really ugly. How bad is an extra `for` loop?

Comment: @jamylak, is there a difference performance wise? I thought specifying what to do can result in a larger set of optimizations, so being declarative would result in faster code.

Comment: @perreal You would have to `timeit` I think two `for` loops would be faster but im not sure. Either way the difference would be too small to notice

Comment: @jamylak, thanks for the discussion. You confused me a little :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  You need to do the combinations 1 grouping at a time and then [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) the result (Actually, `chain.from_iterable` is more appropriate here).

```
from itertools import combinations,chain

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
def group(a,n):
    return zip(*[iter(a)]*n)

for a,b in chain.from_iterable(combinations(grp, 2) for grp in group(lst,3)): 
    print "{0} {1}".format(a,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting close, but you need to apply the `combinations()` function to each tuple in the output of the `zip()` grouper sequence:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

for a, b in chain.from_iterable(combinations(group, 2) for group in zip(*[iter(a)]*3)):
    print "{} {}".format(a,b)
```

Since you now have a *sequence* of `combinations()` results, I used `chain.from_iterable()` to merge the output of each of those into a final sequence.

This produces the desired output:

```
>>> for a, b in chain.from_iterable(combinations(group, 2) for group in zip(*[iter(a)]*3)):
...     print "{} {}".format(a,b)
... 
1 2
1 3
2 3
4 5
4 6
5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `itertools` and `operator`-based solution. Not as succinct as the other solutions but FWIW:

```
from itertools import imap, combinations, repeat, count, takewhile, izip, chain
from operator import getitem, truth
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
slicers = izip(count(0, 3), count(3, 3))
slices = (getitem(L, slice(*x)) for x in slicers)
slices = takewhile(truth, slices)
for x in chain.from_iterable(imap(combinations, slices, repeat(2))):
    print x

...
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(4, 5)
(4, 6)
(5, 6)
```